# C++ error: definition of implicitly-declared

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm writing this linked list program with C++

When I test the program, I got the error

> linkedlist.cpp:5:24: error: definition of implicitly-declared 'constexpr LinkedList::LinkedList()'
>   LinkedList::LinkedList(){

Here's the code

linkedlist.h file:

```
#include "node.h"
using namespace std;

class LinkedList {
  Node * head = nullptr;
  int length = 0;
public:
  void add( int );
  bool remove( int );
  int find( int );
  int count( int );
  int at( int );
  int len();
};
```

linkedlist.cpp file:

```
#include "linkedlist.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

LinkedList::LinkedList(){
  length = 0;
  head = NULL;
}
/*and all the methods below*/
```

please help.

Comment: You dont need the constructor if all you are doing is the iniialization of the members - you already have done that in the header.

Answer (score 35):

Declare the parameterless constructor in the header file:

```
class LinkedList {
{
....
public:
    LinkedList();
    ....
}
```

You are defining it in the .cpp file without actually declaring it. But since the compiler provides such a constructor by default (if no other constructor is declared), the error clearly states that you are trying to define an implicitly-declared constructor.

Comment: but the instruction says that I'm not supposed to modify the header file.

Comment: If you want to define something, you also need to declare it.

Answer (score 4):

You should declare the constructor inside the class inorder to define the cunstructor outside the class. Otherwise you should define it inside the class itself.Your class should look like this.

```
            #include "node.h"
            using namespace std;
            class LinkedList {
              Node * head = nullptr;
              int length = 0;
            public:
              LinkedList();
              void add( int );
              bool remove( int );
              int find( int );
              int count( int );
              int at( int );
              int len();
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

To define constructor outside the class you need to declare it first in public specifier then define it outside the class.

```
#include "node.h"
using namespace std;

class LinkedList {
  Node * head = nullptr;
  int length = 0;
public:
  LinkedList();
  void add( int );
  bool remove( int );
  int find( int );
  int count( int );
  int at( int );
  int len();
};


LinkedList::LinkedList(){
  length = 0;
  head = NULL;
}
```